# Setting a variable "onsubmit" for later usage

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that is asking for an email and an API key on my website.

I need to reference both of the variables later in HTML and I don't know how I would reference a javascript variable in HTML, or other ways to get around this.

I am new to this type of thing and would be grateful for some help. Here is snippets of the code.

signin.html

```
<div class="login-page">
        <div class="form">
          <form class="login-form" onsubmit="storevalues(thiss)">
            <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="email"/>
            <input id="apikey"type="text" placeholder="API key"/>
            <button onclick="setLoginFormVars(); alert(apikey)">Sign In</button>
```

signin.js

```
function setLoginFormVars(form) {
        var email = "";
        email = document.getElementById("email").value;

        var apikey = "";
        apikey = document.getElementById("apikey").value;
      }
```

Nyle.

Comment: It would be nice, if you post some code that what you tried.. that will help us to answer your question

Comment: For a proper answer, explain what _"reference both of the variables later in HTML"_ means and will the form actually be submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display variables in your javascript to content on your web page you don't really reference the variables in HTML, but rather tell javascript to display them in particular areas in your HTML. In the snippet bellow I used `.innerHTML` to set the contents of a particular div so the HTML is updated with the variables contents:

```js
var a = "foo"; // eg your email variable
var b = "bar"; // eg your api key variable

let displayDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
let displayDiv2 = document.getElementById('myDiv2');

// Adding data attribute:
displayDiv.setAttribute('data-a', a); 
displayDiv2.setAttribute('data-b', b); // Add the attribute data-a (this could be ('data-key', api_key_variable) or a different attribute)

// Adding value to the tags:
displayDiv.innerHTML += a; // Add to the contents of the div with the id 'myDiv' to the variable a

displayDiv2.innerHTML += b; // Add to the contents of the div with the id 'myDiv2' to the variable b
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
    <div id="myDiv2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to fit my purpose but i dont want to display the details. I need to reference it later like this. `        <div class="thing1" 
       style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"
        data-key=*API Key Here??*
        data-whitelabel="true"
        data-background="#36393F"
        data-text="#6f42c1">
        </div>`

Comment: @NyleCohen Okay, I updated the code snippet. You need to inspect element on the results to see the attributes add though

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an input html Element:

```
<input id="my_input></input>
```

So when you want to get what the user have typed, this is one way to do it in JavaScript:

```
var user_input=document.getElementById("my_input").value;
```

Finally if you want that to happen after the the user clicks on the submit button of the form, then you have to use preventDefault method so the page doesn't reload.